# Extract keyword from Google search in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I'd like to extract from the url of a Google search the keyword of the search (e.g. for the keyword "car" : http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=webhp&source=hp&q=car&aq ... (here car is between "q=" and "&aq"
but I noticed that the tokens might change ["&ie" instead of "&aq"]).

Being new at regex and Google search I haven't found so far the solution, does someone know how to do this please ?

Bruno

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression for this. Modified from http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html:

```
function getUrlVars(href)
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = href.slice(href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

You can then do this:

```
var v = getUrlVars("http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=webhp&source=hp&q=car&aq");
var q = v.q;
```

Comment: Glad to know it performed for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getParameterByName(name,url) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}


alert(getParameterByName('q','https://www.google.com/search?q=buy+a+pc&oq=buy+a+pc&aqs=chrome..69i57j5j0l2j69i61.1674j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#psj=1&q=buy+a+pc'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Below sample code works for me for a single parameter and current URL but can be modified as per requirement.

```
function extract( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

just use it as shown below,

```
var result= extract("your parameter name");
```