# Regexp to translate Google search words with accent marks

Tags: javascript, regex, url, google-chrome, search-engine

I'm using some code to extract from a Google Url the keyword of the search. Thanks to an answer to my previous post ( [Extract keyword from Google search in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045477/extract-keyword-from-google-search-in-javascript) ) I was able to do this.

But I realized that words using accent marks give me trouble (eg. "chaîne" (French word) is translated "cha%C3%AEne").
Did someone have the same problem and wrote some magical regex ? :-)

Bruno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use decodeURI

```
decodeURI("cha%C3%AEne");
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to decode the string. Use

```
decodeURIComponent("cha%C3%AEne");
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292914/javascript-url-decode-function) and [here](http://ecmanaut.blogspot.com/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html)