# How to get search keywords using javascript?

Tags: javascript, search, search-keywords

What I want to do is to track the keywords my visitors used in search to land on my page.

For example if you search for `stackoverflow` and then click on the link, I must be able to recognize using `javascript` that the user searched for `stackoverflow`

I tried using the `document.referrer`. The problem is that from `https://www.google.co.in/search?q=stackoverflow&oq=stackoverflow&sugexp=chrome,mod=1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8`

it redirects to `http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F`
form which I can't access the keywords.

Is there a way to get the previous URL?

Comment: Why not google analytics? http://analytics.google.com

Comment: I'm making a custom tracker for my site. This way I can handle data the way I want.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045477/extract-keyword-from-google-search-in-javascript

Comment: I don't really know how much better it can be presented than google analytics but ok. You know its free right? And you can output the data in a variety of formats?

Comment: Most of Google search traffic is through HTTPS, so you won't get any information anyhow.

Comment: But I'm 90% done with my tracker. I just dont want to login to GA to check my keywords. @user1702584 the problem is that I'm not getting the URL with the keywords. Its redirecting to another URL and then landing on my page. See question.