# how to get google search url as reference url in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i'm creating a project which needs the keywords from search engines to show users.

i have tried document.referrer but it shows only referrer domain.

if user searches like "buy a pc" then this url is generating by google

https://www.google.com/search?q=buy+a+pc&oq=buy+a+pc&aqs=chrome..69i57j5j0l2j69i61.1674j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#psj=1&q=buy+a+pc

now i need this url when user choose the my website or my site page from google results to extract keywords from url but i have to do this by javascript only.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045477/extract-keyword-from-google-search-in-javascript

Comment: no, i want to get ref url, i know how to extract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is in `document.referrer`

Comment: no bro i'm looking for to get referrer url with parameters
i tried document.referrer but it shows only domain, not parameters

Comment: Yes, I know. And if available, it will be in `document.referrer`. If that is empty, you do not have a referrer URL available to read.  Referrers are not guaranteed to be passed to every page.

Comment: document.referrer only shows http://www.google.com/  

any other way to get referrer url with parameters ?

Comment: `document.referrer` will show you everything you have available. End of story. If it isn't in there, you can't get it.  http://i.imgur.com/OP3ZQ3y.png - as you can see here, it *can* contain parameters.

Answer (score -2):

```
function getParameterByName(name,url) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}


alert(getParameterByName('q','https://www.google.com/search?q=buy+a+pc&oq=buy+a+pc&aqs=chrome..69i57j5j0l2j69i61.1674j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#psj=1&q=buy+a+pc'));
```

Comment: i need that google url as referrer url, i know how to extract